# YouCompleteMe doesn't work with c++

Tags: c++, linux, vim, youcompleteme

I'm trying to configure YouCompleteMe for C++, here is the output from :`YcmDebugInfo`

```
> Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: True
-- Clang version: clang version 3.7.1 (tags/RELEASE_371/final)
-- Flags for /home/jan/main.cpp loaded from /home/jan/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf
.py:
-- ['-Wall', '-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++', '-x', 'c++', '-I', '/home/jan/.vim/.', '-isystem', '/usr/include/c++/5.3.0', '-isystem'
, '/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu', '-isystem', '/home/jan/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/../clang
_includes']
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:41513
-- Server process ID: 23121
-- Server logfiles:
--   /tmp/ycm_temp/server_41513_stdout.log
--   /tmp/ycm_temp/server_41513_stderr.log
```

It's only complete things that had already written in the file. Some idea what i do wrong?

Comment: Looks like this is by design. Quote: It collects all of the identifiers in the current file and other files you visit (and your tags files) and searches them when you type (identifiers are put into per-filetype groups). Source: [click](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)

Comment: The semantic completer only triggers after typing certain characters, i.e. `::` and `->` and `.` for C++. You can trigger the semantic completer manually by pressing ctrl-space.